# NestJS Schema First GraphQL Serialization

Tags: serialization, graphql, nestjs

I've done some research into the subject of response serialization for NestJS/GraphQL. There's some helpful information to be found [here](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/serialization), but the documentation seems to be completely focused on a code first approach. My project happens to be taking schema first approach, and from what I've read across a few sources, the option available for a schema-first project would be to implement interceptors for the resolvers, and carry out the serialization there.

Before I run off and start writing these interceptors, my question is this; is there any better options provided by nestjs to implement serialization for a schema first approach?

Comment: What kind of serialization are you trying to do here? Your response should match the schema created response, and most of the time the apollo server under the hood will take care of that for you, so long as you return the correctly shaped data

Comment: That's a fair point, my schema should match the response. With that said, I'm not really trying to exclude or expose any fields, more to clean up values in the response, rounding numbers or removing nulls for example. I realise this could be done elsewhere before the response, but my reasoning is that serialization is a good place to take care of these data display concerns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's just transformation of values then an interceptor is a great tool for that. Everything shown for "code-first" should work for "schema-first" in terms of high level ideas of the framework (interceptors, pipes, filters, etc). In fact, once the server is running, there shouldn't be a distinguishable difference between the two approaches, and how they operate. The big thing you'd need to be concerned with is that you won't be easily able to take advantage of `class-transformer` and `class-validator` because the original class definitions are created via the `gql-codegen`, but you can still extend those types and add on the decorators necessary if  you choose.